# What does "make of it what you will" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does the verb phrase **make of it what you will** mean? I know what make of something and what you will mean. I have difficulty understanding their combination.

Examples:

> I have asked what the next possible opportunities are for scholarship
> applications. They say it will not be before middle of next year or if
> the student is in the country .... *make of it what you will*. Hard
> times remain.
>
> ‘The beauty of it is that *you can make of it [what you will](https://www.lexico.com/definition/what_you_will)*.’
>
> ‘I have no wish to weary you with the case I have made in the past,
> but *make of this what you will*.’

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression means that you can interpret something in any way you choose. It's an expression used when a situation arises that cannot be easily explained. It may be ambiguous; it may be surprising. It is open to interpretation.

> The missing key was back on the table with no indication of how it got there. Make of it what you will.

> Out of the blue he has agreed to stop smoking and return to the gym. Make of it what you will.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161230/make-of-that-what-you-will-meaning-of-will